# Using slick.js in autoplay mode for a single slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I want to use slick.js for a simple news ticker. So I have a box where text is coming from the right and automatically scrolls to the left in a loop. The problem is that slick.js refuses to move the text if there is just one slide. I want the slide to move from the right to the left and after passing the left edge it should start moving from the right again. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Here is a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ha5q45o/) showing my problem. It uses this javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        speed: 10000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        variableWidth: true,
        infinite: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like slick carousel isn't built to work with only one element. How about using jQuery to clone your slide once so the plugin works? See functional example below:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.slider div').length == 1) {
      $('.slider div').clone().appendTo('.slider');
  }
  $('.slider').slick({
    speed: 10000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yep, doing this conditionally when there's only one slide seems the expedient approach.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Thanks for the suggestion. Appended my answer to check if there's only one slide.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer is good, but it will give you two same slides which you can slide (change). If you wish to show single slide without cloning, you can use `initialSlide` setting.

```js
$(function() {
    var start = 0;

  if ($('.slider div').length == 1) {
      start = -1;
  }

  $('.slider').slick({
    speed: 10000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    infinite: true,
    initialSlide: start
  });
});
```